# Can I edit content on an FTP server through Finder?

Tags: finder, ftp

Is there any way around the read-only access that Finder strictly allows so I can get write access to a FTP server through Finder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/), which allows to connect to a FTP server through a filesystem device.
MacFusion requires [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/), or [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.com/) with the compatibility layer for MacFUSE.

> - Mount files and documents as a "Volume" in the Mac OS X Finder.
> - Work with your files using your favorite Mac OS X applications directly. No manual upload or download needed!
> - Support for SSH (Secure Shell) and FTP (File Transfer Protocol) servers.
> - Uses your machine's native configuration for SSH, including support for private keys and custom settings.
> - Quickly connect to a any server using the Quick Connect dialog, accessible from Macfusion's optional menu item.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This link works for OSX Mountain Lion
http://downloads.patjack.co.uk/dl/Macfusion.zip

Answer (score 6):

Try [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/).

> With the new Transmit Disk feature, you can now mount any of your favorites in the Finder itself, even if Transmit's not running. These volumes are real: drag files to your SFTP server, save a small graphic to your Amazon S3 bucket directly from Photoshop, or roll your own iDisk-like backup volume. It's all possible in T4.

Comment: Transmit is so full of win and you can try it for free in case you are not sure it's worth the price. I find it much more reliable than installing file system extensions like MacFusion and the various FUSE software.

Comment: I'm really interested in the mounting function, but when I use it through parallels, my file's content is lost sometimes. It's weird!

Comment: WingFS is a version app that does exactly the same thing. http://www.wingfs.com/

Comment: The question was about the Finder. Your answer is interesting, but irrelevant.

Comment: Transmit doesn't work to mount a FTP source anymore.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't get around the read-only access, but here are some great FTP clients:

## [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/)

A great free FTP client. This is my go-to application. Anytime I need FTP access, I use Cyberduck. It's not quite as lightweight as Fugu, but it adds a lot more functionality than Fugu. I like the Growl integration with Cyberduck.

[image: Cyberduck, a free FTP client]

## [Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/)

Awesome little free FTP client. As I noted above, this is a lightweight FTP client. It is great for simple FTP transfers and browsing. I do like the dual panel navigation.

[image: Fugu, another free FTP client]

Last, but not least, you can use the CLI. Just type `ftp username@foo.com` at the prompt. If you've used the command line before, you know that `ls` lists directories, `cd` changes directories. Example: `ls ~/Desktop` lists the contents of your Desktop (the "~" is a shortcut for your home folder). `cd ~/Desktop` changes to current directory to your Desktop. To download files, you can use `mget` or `get`. Here's the Apple man page on FTP.

Comment: Fugu is a PowerPC app, the "intel" version is still in beta

Comment: The question was about the Finder. Your answer is interesting, but irrelevant.

Comment: @MarcRochkind I did answer the question, then I gave a solution

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use any one of many third-party FTP clients, some of which are free.

[FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client). Open-source and cross-platform

Comment: The question was about the Finder. Your answer is interesting, but irrelevant.