# Connect through Finder with server, save permissions?

Tags: finder, permission, server.app, ftp

I'm trying to access my FTP server through Finder, I can open the server and access the files. But when I try to change a `.css` file or something and save I then get an error stating that I don't have permission.

I tried this but this didn't work https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538. On my server the permissions are correct.

I edit with brackets.

Someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The Finder provides read-only FTP, hence it isn't working. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119519/built-in-ftp-client-cmd-k-cant-upload-files-mavericks) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24699/can-i-edit-content-on-an-ftp-server-through-finder) with a list of alternative software [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25661/whats-a-good-graphical-sftp-utility-for-os-x). FYI: I'm voting to close this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the "Connect to Server" dialog from Finder's "Go" menu and add your FTP server's URI, the resulting dialog presented when you connect includes a checkbox to save the credentials used in Keychain.

#### Example

*Open up the Connect to Server dialog*

[image: ss1]

*Add URI to FTP user*

[image: ss2]

*Add user credentials and tick keychain checkbox*

[image: ss3]

*Connect and confirm*

[image: ss4]

*Confirm entry was added to Keychain*

[image: ss5]

#### References

- [Is there a Public FTP server to test upload and download? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968703/is-there-a-public-ftp-server-to-test-upload-and-download)

Comment: This is exactly what I did.

Comment: @ThijsKempers - is the entry in Keychain?

Comment: Yes it is in the keychain

Comment: I edit with brackets. Don't know if that makes sense?

Comment: @ThijsKempers - need more info, what i showed above works and I can double click on the entries and it just reconnects w/o prompting for creds.

Comment: Yes, I can connect too. But cannot write/save.

Comment: @ThijsKempers - I'd be tempted to delete the creds in keychain and try rewriting them through the method shown above.