# My username for remote ftp access is different from my macos username and Finder will not let me edit the files

Tags: finder, catalina, permission, ftp

I can connect to a remote ftp server in Finder using the syntax ftp://username@host/path and then supplying the password. I get to see the files in the remote directory and can read them. However I do not seem to have write access to these files. Finder also does not display permissions for them except rather confusingly via Get Info:

[image]

The username used for the remote server is not the same as my username on the Mac. Could this be the problem?

I normally access the ftp server from a Linux machine without these difficulties.

Comment: The FTP mounter built into macOS is very basic and (at least last time I tested) only capable of read-only access. The command-line `ftp` tool is much better, but (of course) doesn't support mounting the server folder.

Comment: As explained by Gordon Davisson, the FTP mount utility used by the Finder only has read-only support, as stated in `man mount_ftp`: `The rdonly option will be set even if it was not specified because mount_ftp does not allow files to be opened with write access on servers.` If you wish to use the `ftp` command, you will have to install it yourself, for example the `tnftp` Homebrew package (https://brew.sh), as `ftp` is not included in macOS since 10.13 High Sierra.

Comment: Thanks for these comments. So Finder does not allow writing to the remote server. I have now installed Filezilla.

I note that if you use Finder to access a remote ftp server and you then modify a remote file by some other means, Finder will not show you the updated file unless you unmount the connection and then reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

The usernames were not the problem. The access to ftp in Finder (at least in Catalina) simply does not provide write access to the remote files.

I have now installed Filezilla. More info at [a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24699/can-i-edit-content-on-an-ftp-server-through-finder?rq=1).